# Site access requests not going to site owner in PWA SharePoint environment

Tags: permissions, site

Why are SharePoint site access requests being sent to me (I am a site collection admin) and not to the site owner? 
*there are 2 other site collection admins and they are not getting site request e-mails.

Someone requested access to a project site, and the request came to me and not the site owner or the two other site collection admins.

Is this a glitch or can this be fixed in settings somewhere? Have not encountered this problem before

Answer (score 3):

May be your email id is given in Access request settings. Hence all the access request are coming to your mail.

To change that:

1. Go to Site Settings.
2. Under Users and Permissions, click Site Permissions.

[image]

3. On the Permissions tab, click Access Request Settings.

[image]

4. In the Access Request Settings dialog box, select the check box next to Allow access requests, and then type the email address of the person you want to make responsible for approving access requests.

[image]

5. Click OK.

Reference: [Changing Site Access Request Email in SharePoint 2013](http://geeklit.blogspot.in/2013/09/changing-site-access-request-email-in.html)

Comment: This was the exact solution I was looking for thank you so much!